# Underlying reasons for different output after removing a print statement in an "out of range of vector error"

Tags: c++, debugging, vector, coredump

I have a minimal code causing said behavior:

```
vector<int> result(9); 
int count = 0;
cout << "test1\n"; // removing this line causes 'core dump'
for (int j=0; j < 12; j++)          
    result[count++] = 1;
cout << "test2\n";
```

**result** is a vector of size 9, and inside 'for' loop I am accessing elements out of the range.

Now, removing **test1** line, the code runs without any errors; but with this **cout** line, I get

> *** Error in `./out_of_range_vector2': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000001b27c20 ***

I understand that this is telling me that **free()** encounter some memory that were not allocated my **malloc()**, but what role does this **cout** line plays here? I'd like to know a little bit more about what's going on here. More specifically, I have two questions:

1. Is this caused by the different state of **heap** on these 2 cases? If so, what exactly is different?
2. Why sometimes accessing out of range elements does not cause error? Is it because it hasn't exceeded vector's capacity?

Comment: Going out of bounds leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), and that's really the end of the story.

Comment: Undefined behavior is, by definition, undefined.

Comment: If you're interested in range checking, consider [`std::vector::at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at).

Comment: What's likely happened is that you wrote outside the heap allocation the vector used, corrupting the heap free list. When you do the `cout`, it may perform a heap allocation, altering the free list such that your transgression goes unnoticed.

Comment: Obligatory link: undefined behaviour can cause time travel https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
cout << "test1\n";
```

does a lot of things, and it can possibly allocate an free memory.

Writing outside the bounds of a vector is "undefined behavior" and this is very different from "getting an error". The meaning of "undefined behavior" is that who writes the compiler and the runtime library simply is free to ignore those possibilities and whatever happens happens. They can do so because a programmer will never ever do those things and when does it's 100% his/her fault. Preventing, protecting or even simply notifying of errors when accessing `std::vector` elements using `operator[]` is not part of the contract.

Technically what could have happened is that the write operation destroyed some internal data structure used by the memory allocator and this resulted in crazy behavior after that that may or may not result in a segfault.

A segfault is when things get crazy to the point that even the operating system can detect the program is not doing what is supposed to do because it requests access to locations that do not even exist (so for sure they cannot be the correct location that was supposed to contain the data being looked for).

You can however get undefined behavior and corrupted data without getting to that "segfault" point and the program will simply read or write from the wrong locations incorrect data, even without getting any observable difference from a correct program. This is actually what happens most of the times (unfortunately).

So what happens when you read or write outside the size of an `std::vector` using the unchecked `opertor[]`? Most of the time nothing (apparently). It may however do whatever it likes after that mistake, including behaving crazy in places where the code is instead correct, one billion machine instructions later and only if that provokes serious damages. Just don't do that.

When programming in C++ you simply cannot do any mistake. There are no "runtime error angels" to protect you like in other higher level languages.